# iOS 12 CacheStorage API gets deleted after browser restart

Tags: ios, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, ios12, cachestorage

I'm currently developing an offline-web-app for iOS. It uses the ServiceWorker and CacheStorage API for storing application code offline.

In iOS 11, everything worked fine.
Since iOS 12, the CacheStorage gets cleared, everytime you restart the browser.

I set up a little demo on how to reproduce this:
It shows you what caches are there on the page/host, and then creates a new cache with a picture in it. So next time you visit it, there should be an existing cache.

1. Go to https://itoobi.github.io/servicebreaker/
2. The page says "keys:  size: 0" (0 caches currently)
3. It creates a new cache called "test" and says "cache opened".
4. Reload the page
5. The page now says "keys: test size: 1" (1 cache existing) (and again "cache opened", but thats not important here)
6. Close the browser (by closing it in the iOS task manager thing)
7. Restart browser and reload the page
8. It should now say again "keys: test size: 1", as there should be an existing cache. **--> on iOS 12, the page again says "keys:  size: 0" here.**

I tested on desktop browsers including the latest Chromium and Firefox, which works.

With iOS 11.4.x Safari, it works.
With iOS 12.x (12.0, 12.1, 12.1 beta 5) Safari, it does not work. Tested with different iPad and iPhone devices.

So the question is: does anybody know what I am doing wrong, did Apple change the API or is this just a bug on Apple's side?
It would also interest me if anybody has similar issues, as I didn't find anything related to this.

---

Code of the test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Home Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <script>
        caches.keys().then(function(keys){
            alert("keys: "+keys+" size: "+keys.length);
        });
        caches.open("test").then(function(cache){
            cache.add("mario.png");
            alert("cache opened");
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you may be opening the browser using a Private instance. If you do that in other browsers this is the behavior they have as well.
I tried it on my iPhone and it worked as it should, retaining the cached image. I am using iOS 12.1.3, so maybe it was an early bug they fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried to install(Put it home screen), maybe this will fix it.

Comment: move this as comment and not as answer.

Comment: no, this does not help. and in iOS 11, it also works in both normal safari- and pwa-mode.